# Autoboot android device when plugged in

Tags: boot

I am trying to auto-boot my Samsung s4 mini (model SPH-L520) I have searched already the web with instruction to change the lpm file to

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

but it does not work on that model, look like the charge animation is placed in different place. can anyone help me with that please.

Comment: The charging animation is placed inside the bootloader (usually on Samsung phones at least). Automatic booting from plugging in would require a modified bootloader which is not possible due to KNOX refusing to flash any bootloader that has not been signed by Samsung. By the way: booting a device consumes more power than the charging port can deliver, because of that, the boot procedure will stop once the battery cuts the power before coming near the home screen.

Comment: I see a lot of instruction like that to boot when Samsung devices when plugged in. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169387/how-to-make-android-device-boot-when-power-is-plugged-in

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices with [KNOX Customization SDK](https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/knox-customization-android) 2.6 and above have the ability to configure to auto boot when getting power.